# If an abelian variety has an m-torsion point, is the set of all Galois conjugates of the m-torsion all the m-torsion?

Tags: abelian-varieties, nt.number-theory

I believe this is the case, but I couldn't come up with a proof off the top of my head, so I want to make sure.

If $A$ is an abelian variety over some field $K$ (I'm in fact interested only in Jacobians, but I don't think this should matter), if $A$ has *some* $m$-torsion point, is the set of all $\sigma(p)$ for $\sigma \in Gal(K)$ and $p$ a $K$-rational $m$-torsion point of $A$, all of the $m$-torsion of $A \times_K \overline{K}$?

Comment: The way I am reading the question, the answer is trivially no, e.g. if we have $A(\overline{K})[m] = A(K)[m]$, which can certainly occur.  Am I missing something?

Comment: In that case the answer is trivially yes: take sigma=identity.

Comment: Then, as I suspected, I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by $\operatorname{Gal}(K)$?  The most reasonable thing I can think of is $\operatorname{Gal}(K^{\sep}/K)$ but then notice that if $p \in A(K)$ and $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K)$, then $\sigma(P) = P$.  So this time I read your question as asking "Must all the $m$-torsion be $K$-rational?" and of course the answer is no.  So please clarify. 

Comment: Or by $\operatorname{Gal}(K)$ do you perhaps mean $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$, i.e., the full group of field automorphisms over $K$?  (If so, for shame: that automorphism group need not be profinite so has nothing to do with Galois theory in general.)  Even so, the simple case where $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and the elliptic curve has exactly one $\Q$-rational $2$-torsion point seems to give a counterexample to what you want.  

Comment: Gal(K) is just the absolute Galois group. I think I know what the problem is. What I mean is all the sigma(p) where sigma runs over Gal(K) AND p runs over all the K-rational m-torsion (p is not fixed!).

Comment: I don't think this solves Pete's question: "$\sigma$ runs over Gal(K)" is still of no use.

Comment: @James: For the second time: If $A_{/K}$ is an abelian variety (or any algebraic variety), the absolute Galois group of $K$ acts trivially on the $K$-rational points of $A$.  So your question is equivalent to: if $A$ has one $K$-rational point of order $m$, must each of the $\overline{K}$-rational points of order $m$ be defined over $K$, the answer to which is clearly "no", as I and several others have explained.  If you meant to ask a nontrivial question, now is your third chance...

Answer (score 4):

No. Take $E=Z(zy^2 = x(x^2+z^2))$, identifying zero with $(0:1:0)$. Then $(-1:0:1)$ is the only real non trivial 2-torsion point of $E(\mathbb{R})$.